# How to modify TokenRegex rule in StanfordNLP?

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I have rule file for tokenregex as

`$EDU_FIRST_KEYWORD = (/Education/|/Course[s]?/|/Educational/|/Academic/|/Education/ /and/?|/Professional/|/Certification[s]?/ /and/?)`

`$EDU_LAST_KEYWORD  = (/Background/|/Qualification[s]?/|/Training[s]?/|/Detail[s]?/|/Record[s]?/)`
`tokens = { type: "CLASS", value: "edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$NamedEntityTagAnnotation" }`

`{ ruleType: "tokens", pattern: ( $EDU_FIRST_KEYWORD $EDU_LAST_KEYWORD ?),
  result: "EDUCATION"
}`

I want to match `EDU_FIRST_KEYWORD` followed by `EDU_LAST_KEYWORD`. If it does not match both parts, then check if `EDU_FIRST_KEYWORD` matches in given string.

E.g. 1. Training & Courses

Matched Output: EDUCATION (as it matched Courses, which should not happen)

**Expected Output: no output**

It is because it **does not match either first part of string or complete string.**

2. Educational Background

Matched Output: EDUCATION

Expected Output: EDUCATION

I tried changing `pattern: ( $EDU_FIRST_KEYWORD $EDU_LAST_KEYWORD ?)` to 
`pattern: ( $EDU_FIRST_KEYWORD + $EDU_LAST_KEYWORD ?)` but it does not help.

I tried stanfordNLP tokenregex documentation, but could not get how to achieve this. Can somebody help me changing rule file?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the Training & Courses the reason why it doesn't math is because of the & I think. Your pattern: ( $EDU_FIRST_KEYWORD $EDU_LAST_KEYWORD ?) doesn't leave room for any other keyword in between. Try changing to $EDU_FIRST_KEYWORD (?: /and|or|&/)*?$EDU_LAST_KEYWORD ?) and see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the `matches()` method of TokenSequenceMatcher to have your rule run against the entire String.

If you use `find()` it will search the entire string...if you use `matches()` it will see if the entire string matches the pattern.

At this time I am not sure if the TokensRegexAnnotator can perform full string matches on sentences, so you probably need to use some code like this:

```
package edu.stanford.nlp.examples;

import edu.stanford.nlp.util.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.Env;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.TokenSequencePattern;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.TokenSequenceMatcher;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.*;

import java.util.*;

public class TokensRegexExactMatch {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize");
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    Annotation annotation = new Annotation("Training & Courses");
    pipeline.annotate(annotation);
    //System.err.println(IOUtils.stringFromFile("course.rules"));
    Env env = TokenSequencePattern.getNewEnv();
    env.bind("$EDU_WORD_ONE", "/Education|Educational|Courses/");
    env.bind("$EDU_WORD_TWO", "/Background|Qualification/");
    TokenSequencePattern pattern = TokenSequencePattern.compile(env, "$EDU_WORD_ONE $EDU_WORD_TWO?");
    List<CoreLabel> tokens = annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation.class);
    TokenSequenceMatcher matcher = pattern.getMatcher(tokens);
    // matcher.matches()
    while (matcher.find()) {
      System.err.println("---");
      String matchedString = matcher.group();
      List<CoreMap> matchedTokens = matcher.groupNodes();
      System.err.println(matchedTokens);
    }
  }
}
```