# StanfordNLP - ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at TokensRegexNERAnnotator.readEntries(TokensRegexNERAnnotator.java:696)

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I want to identify following as SKILL using stanfordNLP's TokensRegexNERAnnotator.

`AREAS OF EXPERTISE
Areas of Knowledge
Computer Skills
Technical Experience
Technical Skills`

There are many more sequence of text like above.

Code -

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner");
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    pipeline.addAnnotator(new TokensRegexNERAnnotator("./mapping/test_degree.rule", true));
    String[] tests = {"Bachelor of Arts is a good degree.", "Technical Skill is a must have for Software Developer."};
    List tokens = new ArrayList<>();

    // traversing each sentence from array of sentence.
    for (String txt : tests) {
         System.out.println("String is : " + txt);

         // create an empty Annotation just with the given text
         Annotation document = new Annotation(txt);

         pipeline.annotate(document);
         List<CoreMap> sentences = document.get(SentencesAnnotation.class);

         /* Next we can go over the annotated sentences and extract the annotated words,
         Using the CoreLabel Object */
      for (CoreMap sentence : sentences) {
         for (CoreLabel token : sentence.get(TokensAnnotation.class)) {
             System.out.println("annotated coreMap sentences : " + token);
             // Extracting NER tag for current token
             String ne = token.get(NamedEntityTagAnnotation.class);
             String word = token.get(CoreAnnotations.TextAnnotation.class);
             System.out.println("Current Word : " + word + " POS :" + token.get(PartOfSpeechAnnotation.class));
             System.out.println("Lemma : " + token.get(LemmaAnnotation.class));
             System.out.println("Named Entity : " + ne);
    }
  }
```

My regex rule file is -

$SKILL_FIRST_KEYWORD = "/area of/|/areas of/|/technical/|/computer/|/professional/"
$SKILL_KEYWORD  = "/knowledge/|/skill/|/skills/|/expertise/|/experience/"

tokens = { type: "CLASS", value: "edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$TokensAnnotation" }

{
     ruleType: "tokens",
     pattern: ($SKILL_FIRST_KEYWORD + $SKILL_KEYWORD),
     result: "SKILL"
}

I am getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` error. I guess there is something wrong with my rule file. Can somebody please point me where am I making mistake?

Desired Output -

**AREAS OF EXPERTISE - SKILL**

**Areas of Knowledge - SKILL**

**Computer Skills - SKILL**

and so on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why `/area of/|..` instead of just `area of|..`? Is it needed for code to work?

Comment: I am getting same error after changing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the TokensRegexAnnotator not the TokensRegexNERAnnotator.

You should review these threads for more info:

[TokensRegex rules to get correct output for Named Entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43447585/tokensregex-rules-to-get-correct-output-for-named-entities/43532621#43532621)

[Getting output in the desired format using TokenRegex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43521697/getting-output-in-the-desired-format-using-tokenregex)

Answer (score 0):

Above accepted Answer by @StanfordNLPHelp, helped me solve this problem. All credit goes to him/her.

I am just concluding how end code would look like to get output in desired format in the hope that it helps somebody.

First I changed in rule file

`$SKILL_FIRST_KEYWORD = "/area of|areas of|Technical|computer|professional/" 
$SKILL_KEYWORD = "/knowledge|skill|skills|expertise|experience/"`

Then in code

```
props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner");
StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

for (String txt : tests) {
     System.out.println("String is : " + txt);

     // create an empty Annotation just with the given text
     Annotation document = new Annotation(txt);

     pipeline.annotate(document);
     List<CoreMap> sentences = document.get(SentencesAnnotation.class);

     Env env = TokenSequencePattern.getNewEnv();
     env.setDefaultStringMatchFlags(NodePattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
     env.setDefaultStringPatternFlags(Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

     CoreMapExpressionExtractor extractor = CoreMapExpressionExtractor.createExtractorFromFiles(env, "test_degree.rules");
     for (CoreMap sentence : sentences) {
         List<MatchedExpression> matched = extractor.extractExpressions(sentence);
         for(MatchedExpression phrase : matched){
             // Print out matched text and value
             System.out.println("MATCHED ENTITY: " + phrase.getText() + " VALUE: " + phrase.getValue().get());
         }
    }
}
```